# OSGi headless running on linux - org.eclipse.core.runtime Unable to acquire application service

Tags: linux, eclipse, osgi, bundle

After weeks of agony I have finally got my OSGi application deployed on linux and almost running.

It is a headless application, my linux is also headless.

I run it with the command

```
java -jar org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar -application eclipse
```

When I run it I see all of my Bundles activate, then just as I would expect it to finish loading I get the below exception. org.eclipse.core.runtime is in the config.ini and in the plugin director.

Any ideas why it isn't starting? I have its start level as 1

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-03-08 05:27:29.804
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
```

Actually I found the solution thanks to
http://www.volker-wegert.de/en/node/65#comment-197

Set the start level to 2 and set to auto start in the config.ini

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.jar@2:start
```

Comment: Hooray, start-ordering dependencies... and you think this is a solution?

Comment: @NeilBartlett it sure is Neil. Its all up and running. Finally! I was loosing my mind :)

Comment: Please post an answer to yourself (which is fine here on SO!) and mark it as accepted so that the question shows up as answered!

Comment: Yes, now everybody can easily see that it's solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I found the solution thanks to http://www.volker-wegert.de/en/node/65#comment-197

Set the start level to 2 and set to auto start in the config.ini

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.jar@2:start
```